# GSM mobile messages with the first octet 01000000

Tags: gsm

In GSM networks, it is found that there are so many mobile phone messages (uplink) with the first octet 01000000. For example, the 28-octet message is:

```
[64,32,238,176,168,33,236,7,11,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,236,40,175,214,203]
```

(each octet is in decimal)

I have no idea what these messages are? It seems that the they are from SDCCH with L2 frame type Bter. Format Bter is used on request of higher layers if and only if short L2 header type 1 is supported and a UI command is to be transmitted on SAPI 0 (see GSM 04.06 2.1). But what is the purpose of them?

Comment: Where did you got this data from? The easiest would be to save it to .pcap file (using GSMTAP header for example) and just let it parse it for you.